# SSAS:Dynamic security is not working unexpectedly

Tags: security, dynamic, ssas

The problem is when I inserted new users  to user table  .dynamic security is based on dimuser and well-known MDX  scripts over the state attribute

```
Nonempty(
[State].[state].members,
(Strtomember([users].[username].&[+username()+]),[meaures].[userstatecount]))
```

**This was used for 9 months and worked fine .**
Its about 2 week that security has weird behavior  and show empty report for some users and for some reports .visual studio is 2015 and sql 2016 .

Answer (score 0):

a screenshot with the error or the error description would help a lot, but consider this, in some domains, Analysis Services may perceive the user name as expected domain\username or localcomputer\username, but in some cases it may return the UPN formatting of the user's name such as  username@domain.com . Therefore you may need to accommodate the UPN possibility if you write any MDX code which relies upon UserName() MDX function.

Another consideration, verify with your system administrator that you don't migrate on another AD or on cloud services.

Hope that helps!

Comment: There is no error ...when I brows cube using the  user credential no record have been returned . I also insert  aa.bbb@domain.local    format  it did not work .

Comment: This problem solved when visual studio 2017 and SSDT 2017 installed